# Calculate nth power of a matrix

Tags: c++, math, matrix, linear-algebra, exponential

I'm trying to optimize my code to calculate the nth power of a matrix.

Before I would just call `multiplySquare` `n` times but that was way too slow. The problem is, it builds just fine but when I run it, I get a failure with exit value `1`. I believe my algorithm is right so what's causing this?

[EDIT] Added recursion termination condition but still, I get the same error.

[EDIT AGAIN] I re-wrote the recursion part again and now it seems to work but only for certain inputs of `n`. I'll have to play around with it more. Any help would be appreciated.

```
void multiplySquare(long long A[2][2], long long B[2][2]){

    long long result[2][2];
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
            result[i][j] = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++){
                result[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i=0; i<2; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<2; j++){
            A[i][j] = result[i][j]; 
        }
    }
}

void power(long long A[2][2], long long B[2][2], long long n){
    if(n/2 != 0){   
        power(A, B, n/2);
    }
    if(n%2 != 0){
        multiplySquare(A, B);
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't have any condition to terminate recursion. e.g., when: `(n / 2 == 0)`

Comment: I just added a condition but the error is the same.

Comment: @user2953932 *The problem is, it builds just fine but...* -- I wish posters wouldn't say this.  A program that "builds fine" only means there are no syntax errors, and the linker finds all the referenced libraries.  It has absolutely nothing to do with whether there are logic bugs in the program.  When there are logic bugs, then it's time to take out the debugger that comes with your compiler toolset and start debugging your code.

Comment: If you have a condition to terminate the recursion, then edit the post to show it in the code. There's no such condition to be seen right now.

Comment: I recommend that you learn how to use a debugger and step through the code to see where the crash is occurring.

Comment: So... how are you avoiding integer overflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your snippet is not what you aim at. I conjecture what you mean is something like this:

```
void power(long long A[2][2], long long B[2][2], long long n){
    if (n == 1) {
        multiplySquare(A, B);
    }
    else if(n % 2 == 0) {
        power(A, B, n / 2);
        multiplySquare(A, A);
    }
    else {
        power(A, B, (n - 1) / 2);
        multiplySquare(A, A);
        multiplySquare(A, B);
    }
```

Comment: This helped a lot. Thanks! Turns out my recursion condition was being met but I needed to set the identity matrix when that happened.

Answer (score 4):

The algorithm to compute the `N`-th power of a number `x` efficiently is:

If `N` is zero, return `1`.
If `N` is 1, return `x`.
Compute `(N/2)`-th power. `y = x^(N/2)`
If `N` is even, return `y*y`
If `N` is odd, return `x*y*y`

If you translate that logic to your case, you will need something along the lines of:

```
// Assuming that the result is returned in B.
void power(long long A[2][2], long long B[2][2], long long n)
{
   if ( n == 0 )
   {
      makeIdentity(B);
      return;
   }

   if ( n == 1 )
   {
      assign(A, B);  // Make B same as A.
      return;
   }

   power(A, B, n/2);

   multiplySquare(B, B);
   if(n % 2 != 0)
   {
      multiplySquare(B, A);
   }
}
```

Comment: The algo is called **power by squaring** +1 for the adaptation to matrices

Answer (score 4):

> I'm trying to optimize my code to calculate the nth power of a matrix.

Since your goal is an optimization, it might be a good thing to consider that diagonal matrices have trivial n-th power, i.e. the n-th power on the elements of the main diagonal.

So, firstly you should diagonalise your matrix. One way to do it is to find the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of your initial matrix, A, and utilize the following relationship:

A = P D P<sup>-1</sup>

where P is a matrix containing the (column) eigenvectors of A, P<sup>-1</sup>
 is its inverse and D is a diagonal matrix containing the eigenvalues.

Then: A<sup>n</sup> = P D<sup>n</sup> P<sup>-1</sup>

---

The above equation:

1. Takes A to a place where rising to the n-th power is trivial.
2. Calculates the n-th power.
3. Returns A back to the original place.